# UIScrollView embedded in SwiftUI has zero size

Tags: swiftui, uiscrollview, uiviewrepresentable

I need to embed an `UIScrollView` in a SwiftUI view hierarchy. I wrapped one in `UIViewRepresentable`, but for some reason my scroll view has zero width.

How do I make the connection between the outer SwiftUI views and the autolayout constraints that define the size of the `UIScrollView`, so that it expands to fill the space given to it by SwiftUI?

In the sample below, I create a simple "content view" to be inside the `UIScrollView`. It is is too wide for my screen (500), so will use horizontal scrolling. It simply draws two colored boxes side by side.

[image]

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Wrapped UIScrollView Test").padding()
            Divider()
            WrappedScrollView()
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct WrappedScrollView: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = MyScrollView
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MyScrollView {
        let v = MyScrollView()
        return v
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MyScrollView, context: Context) {}
}

class MyScrollView: UIScrollView {
    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let content = MyContentView()
        self.addSubview(content)

        // This is how you define the scrollable area with UIScrollView
        content.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        content.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        content.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        content.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        
        // I only want to scroll horizontally
        self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: content.heightAnchor).isActive = true

        // But I have to use this hack to get it to show up. (320 is width of my screen)
        // self.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 320).isActive = true        
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) { fatalError() }
}

// Just two blue and green squares, so you can see scrolling.
class MyContentView: UIView {
    
    init() {
        super.init(frame:.zero)
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) { fatalError() }
    
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return .init(width: 500, height: 200)
    }
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        print("draw \(bounds)")
        guard let c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        var r1 = bounds
        r1.size.width = 250
        var r2 = r1
        r2.origin.x = 250
        c.setFillColor(UIColor.blue.cgColor)
        c.fill(r1)
        c.setFillColor(UIColor.green.cgColor)
        c.fill(r2)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `MyScrollView` class:

```
override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    // unwrap optional superview
    guard let sv = superview else {
        print("this should never fail, because we are INSIDE didMoveToSuperview()")
        return
    }
    // constrain self leading/trailing to superview
    self.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sv.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    self.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sv.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

That should get your scroll view's width to size to its container's width.